# Knockout.js select 'value' as js object from 'options' which comes from ajax request

Tags: ajax, knockout.js

*Off-top:
Title is pretty confusing, but I can't find correct words to describe my situation shortly, sorry for that. If you'll find something better, please suggest yours.
I guess I've done a simple mistake, since I'm new to knockout.js, but I can't find it whole day.*

Here's what I have:

```
<select data-bind="
    value: SelectedPm,
    options: PmList, 
    optionsText: 'Name'"></select>
<b>Selected PM:</b> <span data-bind="text: SelectedPm().Name"></span>
```

JavaScript:

```
function PmModel(data) {
    this.Name = data.Name;
    this.Company = data.Company;
    this.Division = data.Division;
    this.EmpNo = data.EmpNo;

}

function ViewModel() {
    // Data
    var self = this;

    self.PmList = ko.observableArray([]);
    self.SelectedPm = ko.observable();

    // Operations
    ko.computed(function () {
        $.getJSON("/CumulativeReport/GetPmList", function (allData) {
            var mappedTasks = $.map(allData, function (item) { return new PmModel(item); });
            self.PmList(mappedTasks);
        });
    });
}

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

In thsis case I'm getting next error in console:
Uncaught Error: Unable to parse bindings.
Message: TypeError: Cannot read property 'Name' of undefined;
Bindings value: text: SelectedPm().Name

But it works fine when I don't use `getJSON` and using some mock array

```
    function PmModel(data) {
        this.Name = data.Name;
        this.Company = data.Company;
        this.Division = data.Division;
        this.EmpNo = data.EmpNo;

    }

    function ViewModel() {
    // Data
    var self = this;

    self.PmList = ko.observableArray([]);
    self.SelectedPm = ko.observable();

    // Operations
    ko.computed(function () {
        self.PmList([{Name:'aaaa'}, {Name:'bbbb'}]);    
    });
}

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

or if I will use js string object as optionsValue

```
<select data-bind="
    value: SelectedPm,
    options: PmList, 
    optionsText: 'Name',
    optionsValue: 'Id'"></select>
<b>Selected PM:</b> <span data-bind="text: SelectedPm"></span>
```

JavaScript

```
function PmModel(data) {
    var self = this;
    this.Name = ko.observable(data.Name);
    this.Company = ko.observable(data.Company);
    this.Division = ko.observable(data.Division);
    this.EmpNo = ko.observable(data.EmpNo);
    this.Id = ko.computed(function () { return self.Company() + "-" + self.Division() + "-" + self.EmpNo(); });
}

function ViewModel() {
    // Data
    var self = this;

    self.PmList = ko.observableArray([]);
    self.SelectedPm = ko.observable();

    // Operations
    ko.computed(function () {
        $.getJSON("/CumulativeReport/GetPmList", function (allData) {
            var mappedTasks = $.map(allData, function (item) { return new PmModel(item); });
            self.PmList(mappedTasks);
        });
    });
}

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

Can someone point me to what I'm doing wrong?
Thanks in advance.

---

### UPD1

I found the way to make it work. Doesn't looks really good, but at least it works

```
<select data-bind="
    value: SelectedPm,
    options: PmList, 
    optionsText: 'Name'"></select>
<!-- ko if: SelectedPm -->
<b>Selected PM:</b> <span data-bind="text: SelectedPm().Name"></span>
<!--/ko-->
```

My guess is that when ajax call was fired knockout triggered dependencies of `PmList` (`SelectedPm`) and tried to re-render dependency value in UI, but request processed for too long and new value was not delivered to `SelectedPm` in time. It doesn't looks legit, first of all because version with `optionsValue` worked fine.But I don't have any other ideas how to explain it, so it is only my guess and if someone has more clear vision of it or answer, please share it.

Answer (score 2):

Well, the problem is that when you bind your view model to the page, SelectedPm is just an empty observable, so calling `SelectedPm().Name` will blow up, as there is no name property.
I don't know if this is the correct thing to do, but I just initialise the variable with the named property that I want:

```
self.SelectedPm = ko.observable({ Name: '' });
```

In this way, there isn't a problem when first binding to the page.

Comment: I've just tried your suggestion, also I've tried smth. like this `self.SelectedPm = ko.observable(new PmModel({Name: ''}));`
but I'm still getting same error in console and of course my span is always empty.